# Install spark on cloudera vm

Tags: python, pyspark, ipython, cloudera, cloudera-quickstart-vm

I tried to install ipython 1.2.1 using this command:

```
sudo easy_install ipython==1.2.1
```

but it failed with:

> No local packages or download links found for ipython==1.2.1
>   error: Could not find suitable distribution for
>   Requirement.parse('ipython==1.2.1')

So I tried:

```
$ pip install IPython==1.2.1 --user
```

but it failed when I tried to open spark using this command:

```
PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=ipython pyspark
[cloudera@localhost ~]$ PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=ipython pyspark
bash: pyspark: command not found
```

Comment: What are your exports in bash_profile?